# Error from UrlFetchApp when passing Short URL

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-302, firebase-dynamic-links, urlfetch, google-url-shortener

Facing below Exception while calling get request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.

> Exception: Request failed for https://shorturl.com (myshorturl) 
>   **returned code 302**

**I do not get the error when longurl length is 5606 length.
I get the error when longurl length is more than 5609 length.**

```
 var url = shortenUrl(longurl);
 Logger.log("URL:" + url);
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
     "method": "get",followRedirects: true
 });
 Logger.log("Response" + response.getContentText())


function shortenUrl(longURL) {

var url = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=mykey";

var payload = {
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "dynamicLinkDomain": "mypage.page.link",
        "link": longURL,
        "iosInfo": {
            "iosBundleId": "mybundleId"
        }
    }
};

var parameters = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters);
var myArr = JSON.parse(response);
var shortLink = myArr['shortLink'];
return shortLink;
}
```

Comment: add muteHTTP too. Show the full response

Comment: muteHttpExceptions : true is used to mute Exceptions.
I have tried to add also that in my code but I do not get success.
I recently found exact issue is as below                                                                                 I do not get the error when longurl length is 5606 length. I get the error when longurl length is more than 5609 length.

Comment: That will exceed 2kB/call hard limit.

Answer (score 0):

The shortUrl will redirect to another url. `302 Found` status code  informs the client that there is a redirection and provides the redirect url. Try setting the following parameter in addition:

```
followRedirects: true,    
muteHttpExceptions: true
```

**EDIT:**
Based on the new information, that the longUrl length exceeds 5000 characters, Note that `UrlFetch` calls have hard limitations on the url length, which is currently 2kB/call. If we assume 1byte per url character, the maximum advertised  acceptable url length is around 2048 characters.

#### References:

- [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3)
- [MDN 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)
- [UrlFetchApp Advanced Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))
- [Quotas: Current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

Comment: I followRedirects is by default is true and I have also tried to add that followRedirects: true but still facing same issue